# Render twice on async redux's action dispatch

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk, redux-actions

So I am making an async chain of action dispatches in a React component. 
I'm using Recompose but the same thing is happening in a regular class component:

```
import React from 'react';
import ....

const enhance = compose(
  connect(state, props => {
    return {
      store: state
    };
  }),
  withHandlers({
    doShit: props => event => {
      event.preventDefault();
      axiosGetApi(props.dispatch);
    }
  })
);

function axiosGetApi(dispatch) {
  dispatch({
    type: 'GET_DATA_API_REQ'
  });
  axios
    .get('api/getData')
    .then(response =>
      dispatch({
        type: 'GET_DATA_API_SUCCESS',
        payload: response.data
      })
    )
    .catch(error =>
      dispatch({
        type: 'GET_DATA_API_ERROR',
        payload: error.response.status
      })
    );
}

export const UniversalForm = enhance(({ dispatch, doShit }) => (
  <div>
    <button className="universalform" onClick={doShit}>Press
    </button>
    {console.log('RENDER')}
  </div>
));
```

The problem is this - at first button press component's render launched SIX times, and on the next press - two times. Expected it to render only one time on state from Redux store passed a new value. One time. Reducer and actions are one-to-one from redux-actions lib. Is this behavior standard or am I doing something wrong?

Here's a log screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Did you try, shouldComponentUpdate lifecycle method? sometimes connected handlers get triggered without any updates.

Comment: yes i tried Recompose's shouldUpdate() and pure() with same results

Comment: Dont ever put whole store to props

      connect(state => {
        return {
          store: state
        };
      })
But do put the precise data you need

      connect(state => {
        return {
          avatar: state.getDataApiReducer.data.imageAvatar
        };
      })
This resolved usless renders after initial press. But still i get a lot of renders at first press.

Comment: So you solved this?

Comment: @Brett DeWoody sort of. I get double render at first fetch, but no re-renders after.